# need to prove by induction

Tags: induction

Let () be defined recursively as follows: $(1) = $, and $(n) =  (/) + $, $\forall  \geq 2$

where $, $, and $$ are positive constants, $ \not= 1$, $$ is an arbitrary constant, and $ = $

for some non-negative integer $$. Prove by induction on $k$ that $( ) = [ +/(−1)]^ −/a-1$.

Conclude that $ () = [ +/(−1)]^{\frac{n}{b}} − /−1$.

Comment: Your original formatting was quite hard to parse.  I've attempted to clean it up---can you please check to make sure that the edits are correct.  Also, for future reference, please format your mathematics using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: thanks..will take care in future